# Refetching a query using Apollo-Client throws an error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo-client to post a mutation to my graphql server. When the mutation is completed, I want to refetch that data. I tried using the `refetchQueries` argument in the `useMutation` hook, however I receive this error when I execute the code:

> query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in
> the query option.

This is the line of code that sends the mutation:

```
const [addUser, { data, loading, error }] =
    useMutation(ADD_USER_QUERY, {
        refetchQueries:[GET_USERS_QUERY]
    });
```

This is my query (the hardcoded arguments were to see if the issues was due to passing variables):

```
export const ADD_USER_QUERY = gql`
    mutation {
        createUser(name: "Albert Einstein", email: "albert@yahoo.ca") {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Alright so I figured out what the issue was. I had to pass an object with a `"query"` key in the `refetchQueries` array:

```
const [addUser, { data, loading, error }] =
    useMutation(ADD_USER_QUERY, {
        refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_USERS_QUERY }],
    });
```

It's weird though because it isn't mentioned in the ApolloDocs. They simply use an array...

```
// Refetches two queries after mutation completes
const [addTodo, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {

  refetchQueries: [
    GET_POST, // DocumentNode object parsed with gql
    'GetComments' // Query name
  ],
});
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Thanks!

Comment: query name != query const (name+body)

Comment: That got me as well. But it it says to use { query } in the API reference for useMutation though https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetchqueries